# How to customize an error message in a MySQL stored function

Tags: mysql

This is probably a trivial problem for most of you... Below is a stored function I have created in MySQL:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS teamSize;
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE teamSize(IN teamName VARCHAR(50), IN teamYear INT(4), OUT noOfPlayers INT)
BEGIN
    IF teamName IN (SELECT teamName FROM team) THEN
        SELECT COUNT(playerID) INTO noOfPlayers 
        FROM team
        JOIN teamAllocation
        ON teamAllocation.teamID = team.teamID
        WHERE team.teamName = teamName 
        AND team.teamYear = teamYear;
    ELSE
        SELECT "That team does not exist in the database" AS "Error Message";
    END IF;
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

I made this function so I can calculate the size of a given team in a given year. The team name and the team year are parsed in as parameter values. For this function I want a user friendly error message to display if the team name the user typed in does not exist in the database.

For example: I type in a team that does exist I get the following results, as I expected:

```
mysql> CALL teamSize("U11 Orange", 2012, @noOfPlayers);
--------------
CALL teamSize("U11 Orange", 2012, @noOfPlayers)
--------------

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT @noOfPlayers;
--------------
SELECT @noOfPlayers
--------------

+--------------+
| @noOfPlayers |
+--------------+
|            2 |
+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

...But if I type in a team that I know doesn't exist in the database I get the following:

```
mysql> CALL teamSize("jkgefkrkvbey", 2012, @teamSize);
--------------
CALL teamSize("jkgefkrkvbey", 2012, @teamSize)
--------------

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT @teamSize;
--------------
SELECT @teamSize
--------------

+-----------+
| @teamSize |
+-----------+
|         0 |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

What I am wanting for the case where a team name parsed into the function doesn't exist is something like the following:

```
+------------------------------------------+
| Error Message                            |
+------------------------------------------+
| That team does not exist in the database |
+------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

If anyone has some feedback or advice on how I can achieve the above that would be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is the overloading of the term `teamName`.  Since `teamName` is a parameter to your procedure, the following query:

```
SELECT teamName FROM team
```

Is equivalent to:

```
SELECT 'foo' FROM team
```

Which will always return the string `'foo'` once for each record in `team` (and therefore the `IF 'foo' IN ...` condition is always true).  You would be well-advised to rename your parameter so that it doesn't collide with a column name.

Also, you need not perform the `IF` in the manner you are.  Instead, why not:

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM team WHERE teamName = new_parameter_name) THEN ...
```

As an aside, I prefer to raise a SQL error (e.g. by calling a non-existent procedure) rather than return a message string.